# Regex coincidencia exacta

Tags: javascript, regex, test

Quiero saber como hacer que un RegEx coincida exactamente con una string.

Pro ejemplo, esta string: `"26/3, 20:45"`

Usando esta RegEx: `/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*, [0-9]*:[0-9]*/`

`regex.test(string)` devolverá:

```
26/3, 20:45 --> true
boo 26/3, 20:45 foo --> true
```

Como podéis ver, las dos veces me devuelve true y yo solo quiero que me devuelva true cuando encaje la expresión perfectamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues te encuentras en SO en español, en caso contrario es seguro termine cerrada, checa además [ask]

Comment: Hecho, gracias.

Comment: Prueba poniéndole los indicadores de inicio a fin ^ y $

Comment: Escríbela así: `/^[0-9]*\/[0-9]*, [0-9]*:[0-9]*$/`